# What is the difference between i: int = 1 and i = int(1) in Python?

Tags: python

What is the difference between

```
i: int = 1
```

and

```
i = int(1)
```

Is the one better than the other?

Comment: They're not mutually exclusive, you can `i: int = int(1)` too. One is a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), the other is a (redundant) call to [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: BTW, your question's title contradicts your code samples. `i = int(i)` casts `i` to `int`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my title. It should've been "i = int(1)". I'm verry sorry I didn't notice it, next time I will double check everything before posting it. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. I was just asking to prevent confusion. You could [edit] your question and fix it if you want.

Comment: They don't have any relationship to each other, so it makes no sense to ask about a difference or ask if one is "better" (and we generally don't deal in that kind of subjectivity anyway). But the second one is completely redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until you know that you need something else, just use `i = 1`.

In Python, `1` and `int(1)` return the same value (of type `int`), and the latter does more work to do so, and thus is redundant, so just use `1` if you need the integer 1.

If you need a floating point value instead (for non-integer calculations in the future), use e.g. `1.0` (e.g. as `f = 1.0`).

The difference between `i = ...` and `i: int = ...` is that the latter contains a type hint. The type hint states that the variable `i` should contain values of type `int` (e.g. `1`, `2`, but not `1.0` or `'1'`). Type hints are ignored in many situations, so they don't make a difference. If you don't already have a compelling reason to use them, don't use them.

Here is how type hints are used as of Python 3.12:

- [CPython](https://www.python.org/downloads/) (the default, official Python interpreter), as of version 3.12, ignores type hints: CPython saves type hints to `__annotations__` (making them available for future inspection, such inspection is done by dataclasses), but otherwise executes the .py program without doing type checks, i.e. as if type hints were removed.
- [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), a Python JIT (for executing some Python code faster), ignores type hints on function arguments. It respects type info specified in Numba decorators instead.
- [mypyc](https://github.com/mypyc/mypyc), a Python compiler (which compiles Python modules to C extensions, which run faster than the original Python modules) respects type hints. The more type hints the .py source files contain, the faster code *mypyc* generates. Ditto for the pure Python mode of [Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html#pep-484-type-annotations), which also compiles Python modules to C extensions.
- [TorchScript](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#variables) (part of PyTorch), a JIT compiler for a subset of Python respects type hints. The more type hints the function in the .py source file contains, the faster code TorchScript generates.
- There are type checkers implemented as command-line tools (such as [mypy](https://mypy-lang.org/)) which read and analyze (but not execute) .py source code, and print type errors. For example, they report an error for `f: float = 1.0; i: int = f; print(i)`, but CPython still executes the code without an error. (Please note that *mypy* accepts `i: int = 1; f: float = i; print(f)` without an error, even though `type(f)` is `int`, which is not (a subclass of) `float`.)
- There are some type checkers integrated to code editors (IDEs) such as PyCharm and Visual Studio Code. They run in the background and display type errors within the file editing window. Some type checkers (such as *mypy* above) can run both from the command-line and in a code editor.

Comment: Type checkers should not generate an error for that example, did you mean `f: float = 1.0;i: int = f; print(i)`?

Comment: @MegaIng: Indeed, I've just checked it on https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=6e8638b2d5d43a8865ac231ed142c3f5 . Answer updated.

Comment: *"executes the .py program as if type hints were removed"* - could you fix this, please? I'm a bit surprised to read that `__annotations__` do not exist and do not power such awesome core components as dataclasses...

Comment: Also, `torch` JIT compiler **does** take function arguments and return type annotations into account, as does Cython (not to be confused with CPython).

Comment: @STerliakov: Done both: fixing the description of CPython and mentioning TorchScript.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `i: int = 1` and `i = int(1)` have different purposes, although they may look similar at a glance.

**Type Hinting (i: int = 1):** This syntax is used for type hinting. It tells developers and tools that `i` is intended to be an `integer`. Type hints are used by static type checkers, IDEs, and linters to catch type errors before runtime, but they don't enforce type at runtime. It's a form of documentation that can make code easier to understand and maintain. [[1]](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html) [[2]](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/)

For example:

```
def add_one(x: int) -> int:
    return x + 1

i: int = 1  # This is a type hint indicating `i` should always be an integer.
```

**Explicit Type Conversion (i = int(1)):** This syntax explicitly converts the value to an integer. It's redundant when used with the literal 1, since 1 is already an integer. However, explicit conversion is useful when you're not sure of the type of the input or when you receive it as a string or float and want to ensure it's treated as an integer.

For example:

```
i = int(1)  # Redundant for literals but useful for converting other types to int.
j = int("2")  # Necessary for converting a string to an integer.
k = int(2.8)  # Converts a float to an integer, discarding the decimal part.
```

***Regarding your question which one is better?***

The choice between these two entirely depends on your specific needs and context. My 2 points suggestion would be this:

1. Use type hinting when you want to clarify the intended type of
   variables or function arguments/returns without affecting runtime
   behavior.
2. Use explicit type conversion when you need to ensure a value is treated as a specific type, especially when dealing with user input or data from external sources.

Sometimes you may need to use both together, for example check this simple function:

```
def process_number(input_number) -> int:
    number: int = int(input_number)  # Convert input to int and hint the type.
    return number + 10
```